# Rails] Changing the way 'render' method iterates a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render, loops

When you have a partial in

**/app/views/posts/comments/_comment.html.erb**,

doing the following

`<%= render @post.comments %>`

iterates the @post.comments collection like

`@post.comments.each do |comment|`

automatically, even if you don't pass in the collection into the partial.

However, this will render the comments in the other direction, because of the way objects are sorted by created_at.

I want to change the direction: sort the collection in the other way by `created_at DESC`, and then iterate the comments collection.

I would do

`@comments = @post.comments.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10, :order => "created_at")` in the `PostsContoller` and `<%= render @comments %>` instead of `<%= @post.comments %>`, but I was curious if there were any more common way of doing this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely want to do:

```
@comments = @post.comments.order("created_at ASC").paginate(page: params[:page])
```

instead of changing how a Rails helper works! Why would you do that?

You can define how comments are ordered on the association. In the Post model:

```
has_many :comments, order: "comments.created_at ASC"
```

You can also set a default scope to change how the comments are ordered by default.

In the model:

```
default_scope order('created_at ASC')
```

Comment: I wouldn't put the scope on the Comment model (default_scopes are a pain to work with), I'd put the scope on the association in the Post model.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like `render @post.comments.paginate(params[:page])` work, with the order set in your model? eg.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, order: 'created_at DESC'
end
```